# Set date, day, hour, minute, second interval

Tags: mysql, intervals

I need to set a interval in my query, without taking data from another range.

For Example:

1º interval: 18:00

2º interval: 18:14

3º interval: 18:29

4º interval: 18:44

5º interval: 18:59...

i am using this query to take intervals and grouping..

```
SELECT date_format(data,"%Y-%m-%d") as data,
date_sub(date_format((sec_to_time(time_to_sec(data)- time_to_sec(data)%(15*60))),"%H:%i"), interval 1 second) AS intervals,...
```

but the intervals retorns

1º interval: 18:00

2º interval: 18:15

3º interval: 18:30

4º interval: 18:45...

in these intervals, they end up taking data that belong to other intervals.

The real problem, is:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92XK.png)

will repeat the information at two different intervals

Comment: I think this question is not difficult, but it is difficult to understand. Why have the name 'data' for something containing a date? That's confusing. And even though your query is quite long, I see only one interval. Where are the other ones coming from? From the grouping? And what's the problem? What I am trying to say is that enough people see your question, they just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I've attached an image trying to exemplify the problem, and yes, the complete query is not necessary

Comment: Do you want "18:14" or "18:14:59"? If the former, just use a `minute` interval. If the latter, maybe it is just display issue (or a side effect of your use of date_format). Alternatively, presuming the result is used elsewhere for a BETWEEN clause, just change the `x BETWEEN something and this` to `x >= something AND x < this`. If you drop the "-1 second" part, this even takes care of something that might drop through the hole between `18:14:59.000` and `18:15:00.000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a help-table and then the following SQL query:

[image]

```
SELECT * 
FROM `system_verlauf` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d') 
    AND FIND_IN_SET( DATE_FORMAT(datum , '%H:%i'), ( 
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(uhrzeit, '%H:%i') SEPARATOR ',') 
        FROM `stundentabelle` 
        WHERE `15min` = '1' ) ) 
ORDER BY datum ASC
```